# Does Holochain do anything to prevent excessive storage use?

Tags: holochain

If one peer's source chain receives far more events than average, and ends up needing much more storage (and compute) than a typical peer, does the network punish that or mitigate the cost to others, in any way? Is anything for that planned?

(As an example, a decent solution would be something like... however much you contribute to running others' contracts, you get that amount of holofuel, then you can use that to drive any any contract you have an interest in driving, including your own. So if you need extra storage, you can get it by providing that amount of extra storage to others. This might be something that Holo/holofuel does, yeah, it probably does? But I'm also asking about pre-holofuel holochain.)

Comment: Reflecting on this, the obvious way of doing it is to require the owners of a bunch of data to store as much data themselves, or else, if they're offline for very long, evict it. This may sound problematic for social computing, as peoples' data is likely to be referenced by others, but if you need a piece of data that you reference to be stable, you could simply require authors to store it in the chain of a shared storage provider, which you then have the option of covering the hosting costs of.